# strange behavior of std::bind

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I am using this `std::bind` to bind function outside the class and gives a strange behavior.

It somewhat controls the value of private member variables.

```
//MClass.h
typedef std::function<void(void)> Action;

class MClass {

public:

  Action OnLeftClick;

//some other functions here

private:
  int totalContents;

  VScrollbar* _vscrollbar;

};

//MClass.cpp
```

in this kind of implementation it does not make any bug:

```
MClass::MClasss() {

  OnLefClick = std::bind(&VScrollbar::Scrolldown, this);

}

//but when I do this
//otherfile.h

MClass mclass;

void clickBar() {

  mclass.totalContents = 0;

}

void InitComponentns() {   

mclass.OnLeftClick = std::bind(clickBar, mclass);

}
```

and whenever I call the function assigned to `OnLeftClick()` that is `clickBar()`,
the value of `totalContents` does not change in value to 0 (totalContents value is incremented by other functions of MClass).

am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Well, for starters, you cannot bind ``mclass`` to ``clickBar``, since the function takes no arguments. Second, even if you could, ``bind`` would make a copy of ``mclass``.

Comment: totalContents  is private of MClass, how can you set totalContents =0 in clickBar?

Comment: Note that [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) will make a copy (or move but not in this case) of its arguments so the object `std::bind()` will operate on will be a copy of `mclass`. Use `std::ref()` to ensure `std::bind()` operates on the same `mclass` instance.

Comment: @billz I didn't notice that. I dont have my code here. it is only pseudocode. The real is it is on the function of MClass, not there.

Comment: -1 for posting pseudocode.  If you don't understand what is going wrong, why do you think you know what to eliminate?  Write http://sscce.org/ -- reduce real code down to simple, yet still *real*, code that still produces your problem or demonstrates the situation.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` argument in the `std::bind` call is actually the first argument to the function. For member functions this has to be an instance of the class the function is a member of, as all member function has a hidden first argument that is the `this` pointer.

So for your code to work, the first argument to the `VScrollbar::Scrolldown` has to be an instance of a `VScrollbar` class, not `this` in the `MClass`. Like so:

```
OnLefClick = std::bind(&VScrollbar::Scrolldown, _vscrollbar);
```

For the second `std::bind` call, you should only pass it the function pointer, as it's a function that takes no arguments (hidden or not):

```
mclass.OnLeftClick = std::bind(clickBar);
```

I'm surprised the code in the question builds though, as the `totalContents` member variable is private, and can't be accessed from the `clickBar` function.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for starters, you cannot bind mclass to clickBar, since the function takes no arguments. You could modify the function to take a reference to an `MClass`:

```
void clickBar(MClass& m) { m.totalContents = 42; }
```

Second, even if you could, bind would make a copy of mclass. You could pass an `std::reference_wrapper` instead, using `std::ref`:

```
#include <functional>

struct MClass { int totalContents = 0;};

void clickBar(MClass& m) { m.totalContents = 42; }

int main() {   
  MClass mclass;
  auto OnLeftClick = std::bind(clickBar, std::ref(mclass));
  OnLeftClick();
}
```